# Configure Calico CLI for bluemix container

Tags: calico

while I am configure API 
piVersion: v1
kind: calicoApiConfig
metadata:
spec:
  etcdEndpoints: https:....
  etcdKeyFile: /admin-key.pem
  etcdCertFile: admin.pem
  etcdCACertFile:

below is the error I am getting, here what is the admin-key.pem and admin.pem?

C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>calicoctl-windows-amd64.exe get nodes --config=calicoctl.cfg.txt
Failed to create Calico API client: open C:\Users\Admin.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\VoiceGW_Cluser/admin.pem: The system cannot find the file specified.